# Wordpress category name in single post

Tags: wordpress

How to show category name on the custom single post. If the post belongs to category Products, then i need to show this category name with link to this category.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the_category API from wordpress.

```
<p>Post Categories: <?php the_category(' &bull; '); ?></p>
```

Refer [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category) for more details.